# X-Frame-Options are not working correct for me

Tags: java, servlets

I have backend(localhost:8080) on tomcat+java+servlets. 
Front on js(localhost:8081).

I try to use Iframe(insert some content in iframes)(localhost:8081)

So, 
1) if add filter like this

```
`response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW FROM http://localhost:8080");`
```

-works fine, but it is gap in securite.

2) if use like this

```
response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW FROM http://localhost:8081"); 
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

-doesn't work with error message in browser:

> Refused to display
>   'http://localhost:8081/app/jsf/payments.jsf?hide=true' in a frame
>   because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting
>   values ('DENY, ALLOW FROM http://localhost:8081'). Falling back to
>   'deny'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to use
 `response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors http://localhost:8081");`

X-Frame-Options is depricated.

Comment: Mmm.. I think you are wrong. Why do you think it is deprecated?  (https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security#X-Frame-Options)